# Google Scholar distribution of papers by year

Tags: google-apps, reference-management

I would like to look up a topic in Google Scholar and see the distribution of papers over years.

For example, I want to search for "Potatoes". A bunch of results will come back, each with a year and the number of citations for that paper.

Now, I would like to see a histogram of these results so that I can see in which years more interest was received for the given topic, potatoes. It would be a bonus to see the number of citations incorporated, too.

What software can I use to do this? Is there an online tool somewhere?